# How can I create a rule within BigCommerce to place a customer in a group?

Tags: ecommerce

Can I create a rule or script to automatically place customers who purchase a specific product into a customer group on BigCommerce? For example, if I want to sell a subscription, have those customers receive a 5% discount for purchasing the subscription.

Answer (score 2):

You can classify customers into different segments, or groups, by using the Customer Groups feature, which is available on select BigCommerce plans. Customer groups allow you to organize your customers, give them discounts, and restrict access to specific products or categories.

With customer segmentation, you can:

set up a loyalty group — give access to specific products or categories at discounted rates to select customers
set up a tax-exempt group — offer tax exemption to those that are eligible (government agencies, nonprofit organizations)
set up a wholesale group — provide access to products or categories usually hidden from retail customers or give a discount for bulk purchases
set up a members only group — gate content or products by requiring visitors to register an account to browse the store